# Is there any script to do accounting for the proftpd's xferlog?

Tags: scripting, ftp, accounting

I would like to convert from the [xferlog format](https://bitbucket.org/aseques/xferlog-summ/overview) that proftpd uses into per user in/out bytes, to have a summary on  how much traffic does each user use per month.

The exact format of xferlog is this:

```
Thu Oct 17 12:47:05 2013 1 123.123.123.123 74852 /home/vftp/doc1.txt b _ i r user ftp 0 * c
Thu Oct 17 12:47:06 2013 2 123.123.123.123 86321 /home/vftp/doc2.txt b _ i r user ftp 0 * c
```

This is the format that produces the script I am using now:

```
User example.com  user1 transferred (out/in) 0 / 20K, total 20K
User example.com  user2 transferred (out/in) 6.1K / 6.1K, total 13K
User example.com  user3 transferred (out/in) 173M / 173M, total 346M
```

You can download the script from [here](https://bitbucket.org/aseques/xferlog-summ/overview)

Answer (score 1):

Since I couldn't find a script that did what I needed, I created the script by myself.
You can find it at [bitbucket.org](https://bitbucket.org/aseques/xferlog-summ/overview), feel free to use it and send any issues you're having with it.